# Where should I set the '--insecure-registry' flag on Mac OS?

Tags: docker

I am using OS X 10.10. When trying to communicate with our team's private docker registry, it keeps giving me errors like this:

```
Error: Invalid registry endpoint https://registry.xxx.xxx/v1/: Get
https://registry.af-sys.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx: i/o timeout.
If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA
certificate, please add --insecure-registry...
```

On Ubuntu system this error can be resolved by adding `DOCKER_OPTS` into the `/etc/default/docker` configuration file like this:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry myregistry:5000"
```

Does Mac OS have a similar configuration file where I can add the `DOCKER_OPTS` option?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to set it to Docker Machine's / Boot2Docker profile file: 
`docker-machine ssh <machine name>`

/var/lib/boot2docker/profile

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox --insecure-registry myregistry:5000

'
```

And then restart Docker service.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

Comment: could not find `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`  and `/etc/init.d/docker` on docker version `Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e`

Comment: you need to ssh to the docker machine

Answer (score 130):

I was looking for a way to set `--insecure-registry` in **Docker for Mac**. Turned out to be simpler than what I first thought...

In the **Docker Desktop** application :

1. click on the **Settings** icon
2. select **Docker Engine** menu entry
3. add your insecure registries

[image: how to set docker --insecure-registry on mac os x]

Don't forget to *Apply & Restart* and you're ready to go.

Comment: Tip, if your using vpn connection to access some "insecure registry" on a remote server, it seems you sometimes have to restart docker client after establishing vpn connection.

Comment: This is the absolute correct and best answer - why SO wouldn't move it up top is beyond me.. thanks!

Comment: What would be the correct setting for using `localhost` as registry here?
I've tried to enter `localhost:5000` as insecure registry but when I `curl localhost:5000/v2/` the connection gets refused...

Comment: Did you try with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? or maybe you should use the docker-machine IP, which you can get with `docker-machine ip default`

Comment: How would you add these kinds of options: 
DOCKER_OPTS = "--bip=xx.xx.xx.x/xx --dns xx.xx.x.xx --dns xx.xx.x.xx --dns-search xx.xx.xx" on the macOS version of docker

Comment: You can *"Configure the Docker daemon by typing a json docker daemon configuration file"* in the **Advanced** tab. Does it help?

Comment: I already knew that fact, it was more specifically how to add these options in the config, but I have found my answer, ```dns-search``` and ```dns``` both accepts an array...

Comment: This UI is outdated

Answer (score 7):

### Working MacOS Big Sur

This is accessed throught he docker icon -> preferences
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to set it is via the `--engine-insecure-registry` argument to `docker-machine`:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox \
  --engine-insecure-registry myregistry:5000 dev
```

You can also pass other options using `--engine-opts`. For example, set dns via `--engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8`

This essentially ends up setting `EXTRA_ARGS` in `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`

Comment: there are no more boot2docker in new docker version :(

Answer (score 5):

Mac docker's config file was in  ~/.docker/daemon, The configuration you added to the software interface is the wrong configuration for the MAC，because it's an extra "," like this.

```
    {
    "insecure-registries" : [
        "XXXX:5000", \\ <-- THIS ","
      ],
      "registry-mirrors" : [
        "https://registry.docker-cn.com", \\ <--  THIS ","
      ]
    }
```

The right config is

```
    "insecure-registries" : [
        "XXXX:5000"  \\ there is no comma, it is working.
      ],
      "registry-mirrors" : [
        "https://registry.docker-cn.com" \\ there is no comma, it is working.
      ]
    }
```

Comment: For version 2.3.0.5, the file is `~/.docker/.daemon.json`. Did you forgot to type the appendix or it was different for earlier versions?

Answer (score 5):

For docker desktop 2.3.x in MAC , it can be set as follows: Go to "docker" -> "preferences" -> "Docker Engine" and add the following:

```json
"insecure-registries": [
        "localhost:8082",
        "10.23.454.34:2323",
      ]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide an explanation in order to make the given code more understandable

Comment: technically not a URL, a host:port (no scheme)

Answer (score 2):

As of Docker 2.3.0.3, it must be in `host:port` format, i.e you have to remove http/https. Sample configuration

```
"insecure-registries": [
    "registry.com:443",
    "registry-2.net:80"
  ]
```