# Add Insecure Registry to Docker

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker 1.12 running on CentOS. I am trying to add insecure registry to it and things mentioned in documentation just don't work. The system uses `systemd` so I created a `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-insecure-registry.conf` file.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/50-insecure-registry.conf
[Service]
Environment='DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry="hostname.cloudapp.net:5000"'
```

After loading daemon and restarting docker service, systemd shows that the environment variable is there

```
$ sudo systemctl show docker | grep Env
Environment=DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry="hostname.cloudapp.net:5000"
```

But when I run `docker info` I don't see that insecure registry added

```
$ docker info
........
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
    127.0.0.0/8
```

Pushing images to `hostname.cloudapp.net` fails with

```
Pushing application     (hostname.cloudapp.net:5000/application:latest)...
The push refers to a repository     [hostname.cloudapp.net:5000/mozart_application]
ERROR: Get https://hostname.cloudapp.net:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Is there something that could be done ? Am I missing something ?

**UPDATE**

Resolved the issue by adding a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with following content

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net:5000" ]
}
```

And then restart docker

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

After that insecure registry `hostname.cloudapp.net:5000` works.

Comment: While someone beat you to it in this case (after giving you a generous grace period), this would've been an excellent case for a self-answer.

Comment: excellent! I had this error message while "oc cluster up" with Openshift http://www.javamonamour.org/2017/12/docker-insecure-registry.html and your fix solved it!

Comment: I know you _explicitly_ asked for this in relation to CentOS in your question, but to anyone who lands here looking for an macOS solution like I did, it can be done through the GUI now, as mentioned in [the answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492340/1474421).

Comment: `hostaneme` is likely a typo.

Answer (score 217):

(Copying answer from question)

To add an insecure docker registry, add the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following content:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net:5000" ]
}
```

and then restart docker.

Comment: I believe that's the right solution on debian-likes. On Red Hat likes you want to add it to `/etc/sysconfig/docker` as one of the options, e.g. from an Openshift installation: `OPTIONS='--insecure-registry=172.30.0.0/16 --others [...]'`

On Suse-likes I don't know.

Comment: On DigitalOcean, the 1 click Docker image still thinks use use DOCKER_OPTS versus the `daemon.json` file version.  Thanks!

Comment: @erikbwork On Fedora 28 with Docker 1.13.1 from the default package repos, the approach with `/etc/docker/daemon.json` works fine.

Comment: cannot restart docker after creating this daemon.json,
**showing error:** `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` @matt

Comment: Thanks, It works. In may case without port because se port 80 {
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net" ]
}

Comment: It worked for me. I'm using `Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b` and `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` via WSL2

Answer (score 29):

Creating `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file and adding the below content and then doing a docker restart on CentOS 7 resolved the issue.

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net:5000" ]
}
```

Answer (score 25):

The solution with the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file didn't work for me on Ubuntu.

I was able to configure Docker insecure registries on Ubuntu by providing command line options to the Docker daemon in `/etc/default/docker` file, e.g.:

```
# /etc/default/docker    
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=a.example.com --insecure-registry=b.example.com"
```

The same way can be used to configure custom directory for docker images and volumes storage, default DNS servers, etc..

Now, after the Docker daemon has restarted (after executing `sudo service docker restart`), running `docker info` will show:

```
Insecure Registries:
  a.example.com
  b.example.com
  127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 7):

## For Mac

From MacOS desktop

- click the Docker "whale" icon on the menubar at the top
- select `"Preferences..."` to bring up the Docker Desktop setting window
- Then select the `"Docker Engine"`
- From here it should display a JSON excerpt of what is currently in your `daemon.json` file.
- Add a line in the outermost level of the JSON object for `insecure-registries` and provide `ip.address.for.registry:port` as the corresponding value
- click `Apply and Restart`

### Here is visual of that process:

[image: Docker Desktop Settings window from Docker Engine section]

You should now be able to run commands such as:

```
$ docker build -t mysimpleapp .
$ docker tag mysimpleapp 172.16.0.65:30350/simple
$ docker push 172.160.65:30350/simple
> Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [172.16.0.65:30350/simple]
f5d693d2f2fe: Pushed 
66d5de1853fa: Pushed 
f317cd97a2b5: Pushed 
d517aeda4ce5: Pushed 
199d178b1757: Pushed 
latest: digest: sha256:edde4d73130ef9c88d3d273ab4a727e0f8762f0d65802afb01f46eb6877d087c size: 2425
```

Answer (score 2):

For me in Ubuntu 20.04 better way is edit systemd service

```
/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

and add here line after [Service]

```
Environment=DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry=10.0.0.10:6000
```

or it can be done automatically by 2 commands using sed, it will add the line after [Service]

```
sed 's/\[Service\]/\[Service\] \nEnvironment=DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry=10.0.0.10:6000/' /lib/systemd/system/docker.service > /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.tmp
mv /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.tmp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac. [source](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-configure-docker-for-mac-in-configuration-files/25172)

1. Goto `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database`
2. There is an .git repository (.git)
3. Reset to HEAD `git reset --hard`
4. now you have `com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` folder
5. Go into `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker`
6. there is your `daemon.json` file

Comment: I suggest using Docker Desktop to update `daemon.json` if you're using Docker Desktop on the Mac https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856653/2128265

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking to add insecure registry on amazon linux 2:
You will have to change the setting under /etc/sysconfig/docker and then restart docker daemon: here's how my /etc/sysconfig/docker looks like

```
# The max number of open files for the daemon itself, and all
# running containers.  The default value of 1048576 mirrors the value
# used by the systemd service unit.
DAEMON_MAXFILES=1048576

# Additional startup options for the Docker daemon, for example:
# OPTIONS="--ip-forward=true --iptables=true"
# By default we limit the number of open files per container
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --insecure-registry yourinsecureregistryhostname:port"

# How many seconds the sysvinit script waits for the pidfile to appear
# when starting the daemon.
DAEMON_PIDFILE_TIMEOUT=10
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble getting this to work on raspbian/raspberry pi with docker installed via the official docker script ("convenience script"). For some reason the config has to exist in `/home/pi/.config/docker/daemon.json`. Why/Where it is configured like that I have no idea

This is instead of the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` mentioned everywhere else

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add the registry to here:

**/etc/sysconfig/docker-registries**

```
DOCKER_REGISTRIES=''
DOCKER_EXTRA_REGISTRIES='--insecure-registry  b.example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter a similar kind of issue after setting up local internal JFrog Docker Private Registry on Amazon Linux.

THE followings I did to solve the issue:

Added "--insecure-registry xx.xx.xx.xx:8081" by modifying the OPTIONS variable in the /etc/sysconfig/docker file:

```
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:40961 --insecure-registry hostname:8081"
```

Then restarted the docker.

I was then able to login to the local docker registry using:

```
docker login -u admin -p password hostname:8081
```

Answer (score -1):

If you already have a config.json file, the final file should look something like this.
Here `registry.myprivate.com` is the one which was giving me problems.

```json
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
                },
                "registry.myprivate.com": {
                        "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.8 (linux)"
        },
        "insecure-registries" : ["registry.myprivate.com"]
}
```

Comment: not sure if there are other steps not mentioned here, but this is not working for me

Answer (score -3):

Create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file where you want to pull docker images and add the following content to that file

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.cloudapp.net:5000" ]
}
```

Refer to my blog article for an in-depth explanation of creating a private docker registry: https://geekdosage.com/how-to-create-a-private-docker-registry-in-ubuntu-20-04/