# docker Run an externally-accessible registry with self signed certificate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Can i setup  docker Run an externally-accessible registry with self signed certificate or i required CA certificate only after configuration of nginx with ssl self singed certificate i run below command and its given me the error so can somebody help me int that

i)   #  cd /etc/nginx

ii)  #  docker run -d \
    --restart=always \
      --name sogetiaws \
    -v `pwd`/ssl:/ssl \
      -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 \
      -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/ssl/docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl.crt \
      -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/ssl/docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl.key \
      -p 5000:5000 \
      registry:2

Domain Name : docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl

```
ERROR
```

iii) #  docker push docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl/my-ubuntu

```
The push refers to a repository [docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl/my-ubuntu]
Get https://docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`--insecure-registry docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000`

To your local daemon (the one you use to push the image)

Or

add

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000" ]
}
```

to your /etc/docker/daemon.json config file.

Source : [Add Insecure Registry to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker)

Comment: Thanks you for the solution and your valuable time

Comment: If your problem is solved, accept the answer in order to help other people. Thanks.