# Docker: use insecure registry without modifying daemon.json

Tags: docker, ssl, insecure-connection

I'm currently on a development environment, so there aren't certificates everywhere, or they're not compliant (using myrepo.dev.corp.fr where the certificate is *.corp.fr).

I'm trying to `docker push` on an insecure docker repository, but I'm getting multiple errors:

> Get https://repo.dev.corp.fr/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.corp.fr, not
>   repo.dev.corp.fr

Or

> Get https://anotherrepo.corp.fr/v2/: x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority

I'm trying to tell docker that the repository is not secure, to not use TLS or anything, but I can't.

I'm on docker version 18.09.6. I don't have root acces on `/etc/` so I can't modify `daemon.json` or anything under there. And I also can't restart the docker service. However I do have write/read access to `~/.docker/`.

### What I've tried:

- Setting another file as conf with `docker --config-file mufile.json push etc.`, but it seems it's not meant to be used that way ( `unknown flag: --config-file` )
- Using `--inscure-registry repo.dev.corp.fr` in my docker cli. I've tried a few things explained on the website ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/ ). Setting the environment variables as Linux env var doesn't seems to work, does it needs to be set in a file ? For example `export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1` still gets me a "certificate signed by unknown authority". Shouldn't docker stop checking certificate at this point ?
- here ( [Add Insecure Registry to Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker) ) they're using `DOCKER_EXTRA_REGISTRIES='--insecure-registry  b.example.com'` but it's in a file under `/etc/`. So I can't change it.
- I can make my own certificate and tell docker to use it, but I would need to change it on the repo I'm trying to join right ? And there would still be `certificate signed by unknown authority` I guess. Also, it seems a little bit complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

### Questions:

With all the stuff I've tried, I might have done a few thing incorrectly, so mayube there's something to retry here ...

- How does docker uses it's environment variable like DOCKER_TLS : Is it in a file ? Or can I set it myself as an environment variable ? How do I check if docker is using them ?
- Is there any way to tell docker not to check certificates without modifying any file under `/etc/` ?