# Configuring Container Registry in gitlab over http

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure Container Registry in gitlab installed on my Ubuntu machine.
I have Docker configured over http and it works, added insecure.
Gitlab is installed on the host http://5.121.32.5

```
external_url 'http://5.121.32.5'
```

In the gitlab.rb file, I have enabled the following settings:

```
registry_external_url 'http://5.121.32.5'
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "5.121.32.5"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"
```

To listen to the port, I created a file

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
```

Here are its contents

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

But when the code runs in the gitlab-ci.yaml file

```
docker push ${MY_REGISTRY_PROJECT}:latest
```

then I get an error

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://5.121.32.5:5005/v2/": dial tcp 5.121.32.5:5005: connect: connection refused
```

What is the problem? What did I miss?
And why is https specified here if I have http configured?

Answer (score -1):

When you use `docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}` the `docker` command defaults to HTTPS causing the problem.

You need to tell your GitLab Runner to use insecure registry:

> On the server on which the GitLab Runner is running, add the following option to your docker launch arguments (for me I added it to the DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker and restarted the docker engine): --insecure-registry 172.30.100.15:5050, replacing the IP with your own insecure registry.

[Source](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-with-insecure-registry/44963/2?u=lkorbasiewicz)

Also, you may want to read more about it in [this interesting discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker)

Comment: error on docker push ${MY_REGISTRY_PROJECT}:latest. I corrected the question. Login is not needed here. insecure is registered with me