# Access custom docker registry with NodePort service

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a local kubernetes cluster up and running using k3s. It works like a charm so far.

On it I'm running a custom Docker registry from which I want to pull images for other deployments.

The registry is exposed to the host by means of a NodePort service. Internally it has port 5000, externally it's on port 31320.

I can push docker images to the registry from the host by tagging them as `myhostname:31320/myimage:latest`. This works great too.

Now I want to use this image in a basic Job deployment. I'm using the whole tag `myhostname:31320/myimage:latest` as container image entry like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: myhostname:31320/myimage:latest
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a `400 BadRequest` error stating: `image can't be pulled`. If I try using the internal service name of the registry and the internal port instead, like in `private-registry:5000/myimage:latest`, I'm getting the same error.

I suppose I cannot use `private-registry:5000/myimage:latest` because that's just not the tag of the image. I cannot push the image to `private-registry:5000/myimage:latest` because the host `private-registry` is only known inside the cluster and the port 5000 is not exposed to the host.

So... I'm stuck. What am I going to do about this? How do I get to push images from the host to the registry *and* allow them to be pulled from inside the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has a rich documentation on how to implement multiple registries to allow further deployments/pods to access to public or even private registries, to do so you can create an image pull secret k8s ressource ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)), you can either create it by running this command:

```bash
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword>
```

or by deploying this resource in your cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
  namespace: awesomeapps
data:
  # Make sure the you convert the whole file to base64!
  # cat registry.json | base64 -d
  .dockerconfigjson: <registry.json>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

**registry.json example**

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "your.private.registry.example.com": {
            "username": "janedoe",
            "password": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "jdoe@example.com",
            "auth": "c3R...zE2"
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can simply attache this imagePullSecret resource you can attache it to your deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-pod
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: myhostname:31320/myimage:latest
      restartPolicy: Never
```

### PS

You might also consider adding your registry in docker daemon as insecure registry if you encounter other issues.

you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since my local registry is first and foremost for testing and learning purposes, it does not require a login, has no credentials set. I'm not even sure if whoever (I'm still a Kubernetes noob) pulls the image can reach the registry on the network.

Comment: Depends on where you deployed your image registry and your cluster, if they can connect to eachother whether on the same network, or your registry is accessible online with a public IP you can access it or else you will need to set some inbound and outbound rules to provide connection between both k8s cluster and image registry. I hope that helped.

Comment: I've double checked by using a shell inside the cluster. I can ping the registry, so network is OK. It seems like the reason for the error is that the registry does not transmit a valid certificate (self-signed). Now I can either try and configure kubernetes to ignore the cert error, or I can use cert-manager to issue a valid, signed cert. For testing purposes I'd like to take the first route and turn off cert verification. But option B is also tempting because it also carries some learning.