# JFrog local Docker artifactory, cannot push image

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

I am trying to configure and use local docker jfrog artifactory to store dockers:
set up a clean ubuntu 22.04 lxc (under proxmox)

setup jrog using the commands:

```
cd ~
mkdir jfrog
pwd
export JFROG_HOME=/root/jfrog/
mkdir -p $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/
cd $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/
touch ./system.yaml
chown -R 1030:1030 $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var
chmod -R 777 $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var
docker run --name artifactory -v $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

after docker created connected to the
hostname:8082 and set up, user, created a new docker repository named **ubuntutest**.
my host name is **docker-registry**
from another computer in the network, i have  login

> docker login docker-registry

now i get the error:

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://docker-registry:8082/v2/": remote error: tls: unrecognized name

i tried to investigate but i dod not found any logs with the process or the error inside in the host docker-registry and in the docker artifactory

Comment: The address docker-registry.jfrog.io doesn't seem like an active server, are you sure you are using the correct one?

Comment: yes i think i saw this also,
i removed the .jfrog.io at the logging command 
and now i cannot login :(
ocker login docker-registry
Username: admin
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get "https://docker-registry/v2/": dial tcp XXXXX:443: connect: connection refused

Comment: when i add .art.local to the host name,
i get the error:
docker login docker-registry.art.local
Username: admin
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get "https://docker-registry.art.local/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for bad5c28f1162f271712306d5f1943038.7160c6a3973a36e82226b20c9442c81c.traefik.default, not docker-registry.art.local

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the commands, I see you're using the repository path method for the accessing the docker repositories in Artifactory. In that case, use the full hosname with the port combination to deploy the docker image.

For example: If test.example.com is the DNS of the Artifactory,

Step-1: $ docker login test.example.com:8082

Step-2: $ docker tag <IMAGE_ID> test.example.com:8082/ubuntutest/ubuntu:22.04

Step-3: $ docker push test.example.com:8082/ubuntutest/ubuntu:22.04

This should help to deploy your image successfully to the target repository.

Comment: i cannot pass the login stage,

Comment: i have updated the question , i have a problem in the login stage

Comment: Looks like an SSL handshake error! Please add the hostname and port combination as an insecure registry by following the steps here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43482179/12378094