# Why can't login to harbor server form client at plain HTTP case?

Tags: macos, http, docker, https, harbor

Installed harbor on a host. Using plain HTTP protocol.

The IP is `192.168.33.10`.

I can login it from harbor server itself:

```
sudo docker login 192.168.33.10
```

And can access it from browser:

```
http://192.168.33.10
```

But can't login it from other client(Mac, [installed docker use it](https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg)). The error message is:

```
docker login 192.168.33.10
Username: user1
Password: (my_password)
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.33.10/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.33.10:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

From Harbor documentation there has this notice:

https://github.com/vmware/harbor/blob/master/docs/installation_guide.md

> IMPORTANT: The default installation of Harbor uses HTTP - as such, you will need to add the option --insecure-registry to your client's Docker daemon and restart the Docker service.

Both the harbor host and client host set `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.33.10"] }
```

and restarted docker. However, it not works.

If don't setup harbor under HTTPS protocol now, is there a way to access it from client correctly?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492340/8711328

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

It's unnecessary to set `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on client. Mac has another way:

[image]

Apply and Restart