# How to save all Docker images and copy to another machine

Tags: docker

I have the below list of images present on my system and want to copy all these images to a remote machine.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
u14_py269           latest              6a1ec0b508b3        4 days ago          885.9 MB
u12_py273           latest              c2a804894851        4 days ago          686 MB
u12_core            latest              0d61eba80df2        4 days ago          629.1 MB
c6_py266            latest              cb1a94742d59        4 days ago          1.32 GB
c6_core             latest              77c2ed19d87f        4 days ago          1.278 GB
c7_py275            latest              bb1d3de68452        4 days ago          1.117 GB
c7_core             latest              ca14a76e9cca        4 days ago          1.081 GB
u14_py35            latest              d110c7e4a1f5        5 days ago          914.5 MB
u14_py34            latest              085a37cb8614        5 days ago          830.7 MB
u14_py276           latest              8927c6167930        5 days ago          834.1 MB
u14_core            latest              93ead5abc25b        5 days ago          776.9 MB
centos              centos6             36877b5acebb        5 days ago          228.9 MB
ubuntu              latest              36248ae4a9ac        5 days ago          188 MB
ubuntu              12.04               94a7cb19a65b        5 days ago          137.8 MB
edgester/gerrit     latest              ce4e3238052a        6 days ago          735.2 MB
u14_as374_py276     latest              fa5fb7189d70        11 days ago         1.497 GB
c721_as373_py275    latest              03ccf6961d0c        11 days ago         844.3 MB
c721_as373_py35     latest              b5fece3dd45b        11 days ago         1.127 GB
c171_con_core       latest              8af0d24a38a0        2 weeks ago         377.2 MB
u14_as374_php55     latest              29df638e363a        3 weeks ago         1.073 GB
j_u14_as374_php55   latest              29df638e363a        3 weeks ago         1.073 GB
centos              centos7             c8a648134623        8 weeks ago         196.6 MB
centos              latest              c8a648134623        8 weeks ago         196.6 MB
j_u14_as374_py276   latest              28f379d60882        10 weeks ago        871.5 MB
ubuntu              14.04               89d5d8e8bafb        10 weeks ago        187.9 MB
```

Currently I am using method suggested in [save and load Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository), but I believe there must be a better way to deal with all images.

Comment: What is the problem with `docker save/load` ?

Comment: @Auzias in save/load method I will have to do it for 1 image at a time, looking for optimal way to deal with all images in one go.

Comment: That why bash is powerful. It can iterate and perform loops. See the answer of @kpie. And one command line is enough: `docker save $(docker images -q)`

Comment: @PavanGupta Did you find a better way to automate this process?

Comment: @AsmeJust not really, I needed it only once, however response from Franklin Piat looks promising.

Comment: Yeah , I saw it but it's solution is not detailed enough ... Am currently backing up one by one

Answer (score 143):

If you want to export all images at once, create one big tar file:

```
docker save $(docker images -q) -o /path/to/save/mydockersimages.tar
```

If you want to save multiples images in one `.tar` file:

```
IDS=$(docker images | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(debian|centos)/) print $3}')
docker save $IDS -o /path/to/save/somedockersimages.tar
```

Finally, if you want to export multiple many images, with one `.tar` file per images (not disk efficient: common layer are saved in each `.tar` file):

```
docker images | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(openshift|centos)/) print $1 " " $2 " " $3 }' | tr -c "a-z A-Z0-9_.\n-" "%" | while read REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE_ID
do
  echo "== Saving $REPOSITORY $TAG $IMAGE_ID =="
  docker  save   -o /path/to/save/$REPOSITORY-$TAG-$IMAGE_ID.tar $IMAGE_ID
done
```

You may also want to save the list of images so that the restored images can be tagged:

```
docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' > mydockersimages.list
```

**On the remote machine**, you can `load` (import) the images:

```
docker load -i /path/to/save/mydockersimages.tar
```

and tag the imported images:

```
while read REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE_ID
do
        echo "== Tagging $REPOSITORY $TAG $IMAGE_ID =="
        docker tag "$IMAGE_ID" "$REPOSITORY:$TAG"
done < mydockersimages.list
```

For more information about save/load, read: *[How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository)*

Comment: I made the sinle huge tar and loaded it. got all images but none have repository or title/Tags. Now how the heck I'm suppose to know what images I have?

Comment: @Bsienn did it take so much time?

Comment: @suhayab no, On my system it took 20 or so mins.

Comment: Note that you may get hiccups using the "saving tags script" mentioned above, if you have images, which do not have any tags `<none>`. Perhaps an additional `| grep -v '<none>'` might do the trick here already.

Comment: I am looking to move a set of 6 containers created via docker-compose.yml to another computer.  Will this method work?  Will it also grab all volumes?  Is that needed?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically tag the images in that one-line docker save command (`docker save $(docker images -q) -o mydockersimages.tar`) so that the image names are preserved during the save/load process? I don't have the ability to run that additional tagging script on the other machine

Answer (score 51):

With windows server hosting the command is a little different. Using [@EthanSN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723249/5446749) answer I found the following worked - using go formatting:

```sh
docker save $(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}') -o allinone.tar
```

And the load command:

```sh
docker load -i allinone.tar
```

Worked perfectly with no need for the importing machine to download any images.

Comment: This answer if preferable for a couple of reasons.  One: it doesn't use sed and awk to parse the output of docker commands, and instead produces the correct format from one command to the next.  Two: it preserves the tags when you load, without the need to save them in a separate file and re-tag the images after loading.

Comment: This is a nice solution for a Windows OS, but this works only with the power shell and not with cmd

Comment: It says: Error response from daemon: invalid reference format

Comment: it happens because of `<none>:<none>` images, to exclude it: `docker save $(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | grep -v "<none>:<none>") -o allinone.tar`

Answer (score 29):

Save all images with `name:tag` to one `tar` file:

```
docker save $(docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }') -o allinone.tar
```

Then, load all images:

```
docker load -i allinone.tar
```

Comment: easy and clean solution!

Comment: @rfay i don't think that's a better approach as you will lose all the titles and tags

Comment: @MarkMcDonagh I checked it and you're right, I'll delete the command about using `docker images -q` as misleading.

Comment: Getting `Error response from daemon: invalid reference format`

Comment: @Zoinks at which step? Try split command. 1. ```docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }'``` 2 docker save some_img:some_tag -o test.tar 3 docker load -i test.tar

Comment: used `grep -v ` to exclude none tagged images fixed the invalid reference format error for me.  
Here was worked for me:
`docker save $(docker images | grep -v \<none\> | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }') -o allinone.tar`

Answer (score 12):

Thanks a lot all your awnsers, but I find a basic and safe solution [to save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/):

```
docker save -o ubuntu.tar myjenk:latest jenkins/jenkins:lts

REPOSITORY          TAG                    
myjenk              latest    
jenkins/jenkins     lts
```

after to [restore images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/):

```
docker load < ubuntu.tar
```

Answer (score 6):

Script to perform Docker save and load function (tried and tested):

Docker Save:

```
#!/bin/bash

#files will be saved in the dir 'Docker_images'
mkdir Docker_images
cd Docker_images
directory=`pwd`
c=0
#save the image names in 'list.txt'
doc= docker images | awk '{print $1}' > list.txt
printf "START \n"
input="$directory/list.txt"
#Check and create the image tar for the docker images
while IFS= read -r line
do
     one=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
     two=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 1-3`
     if [ "$one" != "<none>" ]; then
             c=$((c+1))
             printf "\n $one \n $two \n"
             docker save -o $two$c'.tar' $one
             printf "Docker image number $c successfully converted:   $two$c \n \n"
     fi
done < "$input"
```

Docker Load:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd Docker_images/
directory=`pwd`
ls | grep tar > files.txt
c=0
printf "START \n"
input="$directory/files.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
     c=$((c+1))
     printf "$c) $line \n"
     docker load -i $line
     printf "$c) Successfully created the Docker image $line  \n \n"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: This is an undervalued answer. Great scripts that save (backup!) all images! Other than most answers, this saves them as separate files. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

Using a registry, you can have a workflow similar to Git. Modify your container locally, commit changes to a local image, then push your image to the registry. You can then pull the image from your remote machine.

You can use the public Docker Hub, or you can set up your own registry server.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/

Comment: if remote server does not have public internet access this solution won't work but it's useful anyhow.

Comment: This should ideally be the accepted answer, given the utility already provided by the docker.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bash to iterate through the response to `docker images` running `docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>` on each image, and then (assuming you saved them all to one folder) you can zip it up and scp it to the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in zsh:

```
docker image ls | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} zsh -c 'docker save {} >  $(echo {} | grep -oE "[^/]+$").tar'
```

Answer (score 0):

to save and load all docker images to separated tar file you can use follow commands (I've tested in MacOs Sonoma):

save:

```
docker images | grep -v REPOSITORY | while read line
do
  filename=$( echo "$line" | awk '{print $1":"$2".tar"}' | sed 's|:|@|g ; s|/|+|g' )
  option=$( echo "$line" | awk '{print $1":"$2}' )
  echo "docker save ${option} -o ${filename}"
  docker save "${option}" -o "${filename}"
done
```

load:

```
ls *.tar | while read line
do
   filename=$( echo "$line" )
   echo "docker load -i ${filename}"
   docker load -i "${filename}"
done
```