# How to copy docker images from one host to another?

Tags: docker

Let say I have 10 docker images. In all the 10 docker images many layers are similar.

While using `docker save -o`, saved image is standalone and therefore images size grow bigger. (~ For 10 images size is around 9GB )

After pulled docker images, I explore:

```
/var/lib/docker
  --- aufs (~3GB only)
  --- containers (Few KBs)
  --- image (Few KBs)
  --- ...
  --- mnt
```

Is there anyway to efficiently export images ?

I also tried copy-paste aufs and image folder to new host. But some containers can't start.

While inspect log:

`/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Note: I already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository) . This question is not duplicate of it. It didn't solve my use case which I mentioned above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy docker images from one host to another without via repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository)

Comment: The best solution is to run a registry server, your own private server can be spun up in a container, TLS encrypted sessions, and password protected if security is a concern.

Comment: Of course, I can run registry server. But I want to carry my docker images in portable media like USB or CD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save all Docker images and copy to another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575674/how-to-save-all-docker-images-and-copy-to-another-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a correct approach. But Below method worked for me. I tested with 30 [Kolla Openstack Docker Images](https://github.com/openstack/kolla).

**Why I have problem with `docker save` ?**

As I said, I have 30 docker images. While I save using `docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>`. Total size is 15 GB which is too BIG to portable.

**What I did ?**

**Long Story Short:** I copied aufs and image folder carefully.

**Step 1:**

In the machine you want to export : Make sure you have only images(which are to be export). Remove all the containers which are running and stopped.

In the machine you want to import:  Make sure You don't have any images and containers.

**Step 2:**  `tar -cvf docker-images.tar /var/lib/docker/aufs /var/lib/docker/image` It will zip all of your image layers and its database into a single tar file. **Size is only 3 GB**

**Step 3:**  In the machine, you want to import images,

`tar -xvf docker-images.tar -C /var/lib/docker/`.

Now restart docker. `service docker restart`.