# How to start docker containers using images loaded from another server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers

I have a project which consists of several services which are defined in a **docker-compose.yaml** file.

When I run **docker-compose up -d**  several docker images are created and then each service runs in its own container.

I have followed the steps here [How to save all Docker images and copy to another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575674/how-to-save-all-docker-images-and-copy-to-another-machine) in order to save the images so that I can use them on another customer PC.

I ran this to save the images:

```
sudo docker save $(sudo docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }') -o  my_project.tar
```

And I can load this by doing:

```
sudo docker load -i my_project.tar
```

This appears to have saved and loaded the images as I check with the following command and all the imaegs do appear with the correct names and tags:

```
sudo docker images
```

But at this point there are no contianers running.  How do I actually start each container the same way they were started with the **docker-compose up** command when using the original project?

Comment: So you need two things 1: tar file having multiple images 2: a docker-compose file to describe how each image should load. Ref: https://eking-30347.medium.com/exporting-multiple-docker-images-alongside-docker-compose-f2db5d4a1632

Comment: @Gupta yes this worked :) thanks very much you are THE MAN!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of this is that you **must** have copy the `docker-compose.yml` file to the target system.

So you need two things

**1:** tar file having multiple images

**2:** docker-compose file to describe how each image should load.

Ref: [Exporting Multiple Docker Images Alongside Docker-Compose](https://eking-30347.medium.com/exporting-multiple-docker-images-alongside-docker-compose-f2db5d4a1632)