# How do I run a Docker container on a USB drive?

Tags: linux, docker, usb

Suppose we have the Linux OS installed on two identical machines that supports the version of latest Docker. Then suppose we build a container image based on this OS. We can assume this image will now run on either machine. We now put this image onto a USB drive and plug it in the other identical machine.

Now, the hard part... is it possible, using that image on the USB drive to run the container on the same USB drive itself while plugged into the machine?

I'm trying to save and/or minimize memory used by the host OS by utilizing the memory on the USB drive as much as possible.

If this is possible, how would I go about setting up a demo case?

Comment: is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I see this question as "how do I persist Docker data on a USB device?".

On your machines, you need to mount your USB device into `/var/docker`. And then restart your Docker service.

However, with this solution, when you unplug the USB device, all of the containers have to be stopped. Otherwise, ***data will be lost***.