# docker install on private network without network instructions

Tags: docker

I have to install Docker on windows 7 in a private netwrok with no internet access.
I can download anything and bring it in by usb from another computer.

How do I intall and use docker?
Meaning: From installation, (what to install and how to setup) to creating the first image.
Most of the instruction I found use proxy and I cant use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The installation itself involve copying [`docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0-rc1/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe), renaming it to docker-machine.exe, and creating a virtualbox machine with it.

The issue is that it will attempt to download `boot2docker.iso` (the tinyCore-based linux image which includes docker pre-installed)
That means you need to copy that file on your usb key first, from [`boot2docker/boot2docker/releases`](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases).
From [issue 539](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/539):

```
docker-machine create mydocker --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=file:///Users/auser/Downloads/boot2docker.iso --driver=virtualbox
```

You will need a similar docker setup on a machine with internet access in order to:

- docker pull the images you want
- [`docker save` them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/6309)
- copy them on the USB key
- copy them on your offline server, in C:\Users... (which is the only folders mounted in boot2docker VM)

Then you need to open an ssh session

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

And within that session, you can access the folder where the saved images are copied, and [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) them.