# Where can i get docker image off line?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

In my working environment , i can't  connect to the network, but i can connect to the download machine  ,which can connect to network .

But i do not know how to find a docker image and download it .

The website  docker hub  just show the command such as  "docker pull nginx"  , but i can't  connect to the network ,it is useless for me .

**My question:**

Now, I have install docker by download docker-engine.deb.
where can I get a  docker image off line?

Comment: I think, this could solve your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need access to a registry where docker images are stored. But if you don't have images and no registry with images yet, than you have to pull the image from the internet.

A recommended way could be:

Install docker on a machine (maybe your local machine) with internet access and pull an image:

```
$ docker pull busybox
```

Use `docker save` to make a `.tar` of your image

```
$ docker save busybox > busybox.tar
```

or you can use the following syntax

```
$ docker save --output busybox.tar busybox
```

Reference is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#examples).

You can use a tool like `scp` to send the `.tar` to your Docker server where you don't have internet access.
Now you can use `docker load` to extract the `.tar` and get your image:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

$ docker load < busybox.tar.gz

Loaded image: busybox:latest
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
busybox             latest              769b9341d937        7 weeks ago         2.489 MB
```

Reference is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/#examples)