# JHipster - Using docker-compose on remote server

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

I would like to setup my JHipster project on a remote server utilising `docker-compose` as per [here](http://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/).

Am I right in thinking (for the simplest approach), these are the steps I might follow:

- Install **docker** on remote system.
- Install **docker-compose** on remote system.
- On laptop (with app src code) run `./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build` to produce a docker image of the application.
- Copy the image produced by this to remote server like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/2440661).
- Install this image on remote system.
- On laptop copy relevant yml files from `src/main/docker`  to a directory (e.g. `dir/on/remote`) on the remote server.
- Run `docker-compose -f dir/on/remote/app.yml up` on the remote server.

Thanks for your help.

Also any suggestions on how this process may be improved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting that your server is Ubunutu, 
SSH to your server,

Install **docker**, **docker-compose**, **install JAVA and set JAVA_HOME**

Two approches

1. create docker image and push it to docker hub if you have docker hub account
2. create docker image within server

Second approch would be better to reduce the confusion

Clone your repo to server

```
cd <APPLICATION_FOLDER>
```

Do

```
./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build -DskipTests
```

List the images created

```
docker images
```

You can ignore -DskipTests , if you are writing test code.

Do

```
docker-compose -f /src/main/docker/app.yml up -d
```

List containers running

```
docker ps -a
```

Logs of the container

```
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. In the end I created the app image locally and copied and installed it onto my server. Both your suggestions are valid options which I may investigate in the future.

Comment: Do you use a nginx on your server to access your docker ?

Comment: No what is the need of using nginx to access docker?