# Clone Docker containers with data to another Host

Tags: docker, containers, clone

I have two running docker containers.
one container has MySQL with data, another one container has Java web application in Tomcat.

How to clone MySQL container to another Docker host with data?

Tried Save/Load method. but no success because doesn't have data

but Java web application container is working

Comment: docker commit https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ then Save/Load? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/5330223

Comment: Upload them to https://hub.docker.com/ and download from another docker host?

Comment: Yes 
Source Machine - 
docker commit old newcontainer
docker save newcontainer > /tmp/newimage.tar 
Destination Machine-
docker load < /tmp/newimage.tar
docker run --name containername -d -p 3306:3306  newcontainer

Comment: yes.. `docker commit` https://gist.github.com/thaJeztah/8d0e901bd21329d80cf2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docker way to save a container is using [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/). However:

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

Thus data saved in volumes won't be part of the commited container. This is the case for the MySQL docker image which saves the data under `/var/lib/mysql` and declares it as a docker volume.

There is a two step solution:

1. Commit the container using `docker commit` into a new image and transfer this image to the other machine.
2. Copy the data folder from the old container using `docker cp <mysql-container>:/var/lib/mysql ./mysql-data` and transfer the `mysql-data` folder to the new machine. When starting the new container
       on the new host, run it using `docker run -v ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql ...`. This will mount the data folder from the old container, and you should get an identical container with data.

Comment: can you share full command to start new container in new host

Comment: @Mahadevan The commands to start mysql are in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/. For your question adding `-v ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql` to the run command is the relevant part. I don't know what specific configuration you pass to the container. But `docker run --name mysql -v ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql` will give a mysql container with data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating data Volume container? Mount volume directory to mysql container

```
  docker create -v /var/lib/mysql --name mysqldata mysql
```

Refer this link for more details
https://www.melvinvivas.com/using-docker-data-volume-with-a-mysql-container/