# Must specify at least one container source

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

I am trying to save a Docker image inside VM so that I can load to my windows.
While saving the images, I got an error stating "permission is denied" to create a .tar file.

```
docker save -o /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tensorflow.tar user/tensorflow-serving-devel
```

user/tensorflow-serving-devel is the image ID here . Trying this gave me:

> open /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/.docker_temp_783580193: permission denied.

I am using Docker Toolbox here. I referred [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository) to create the .tar file.

[image]

Edit : I created the file .tar by

```
docker@default : docker save -o tensorflow.tar user/tensorflow-serving-devel
docker@default : ls \
>
tensorflow.tar
docker@default : docker cp tensorflow.tar /c/Users/usr/Downloads/
```

Error:

> must specify at least one container source

How do I copy this .tar file that container image?

Comment: You can try using FileZilla or any other software to connect to SFTP in the VM. use docker/docker or docker/tcuser with port 22 on the VM's IP address.

Comment: docker cp copy files from host to container or container to host , and it can not use it to copy from VM to HOST machine.

Comment: if you can browse "/c/Users/usr/Downloads/" inside VM then use simple COPY command to copy tar file into this directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the *[container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) source* as follows in your case:

```
docker cp tensorflow.tar tensorflow-vm:/c/Users/usr/Downloads/
```

Where `tensorflow-vm` is the example name of your *container*, what can be found using

```
docker ps -a
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use Docker Swarm to add config.