# copy docker image to docker-machine and get it working

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-image

Here's what I want to accomplish;-

1. many instances of an app running on different ip addresses all talking to each other
2. Use docker to test that out on a single machine with lots of containers or docker machines talking to each other.

I'm new to docker and I can't get it to do what I want.

It's easy to follow the basic instructions and get a container running but going beyond that I encounter lots of problems trying to get to where I need to be.

I created an image and got it to run in in a container. But then to my surprise the drive is not isolated. What the container writes appears on my local drive, which is weird but OK, move on.

Because I want a few instances, with different IP addresses but all with the same port I tried to copy the images to a docker-machine.

So I created a docker machine (virtual box), saved images, copied them over (though I had to create symbolic links to /tmp because there's no enough space in /home/docker!!) and loaded them. So they now appear in the the list of images on the docker machine

Then I tried to start the linked images, but.. one of them is complaining about a file missing, even though I'd saved and copied and loaded the image.

I'm thinking that maybe I've got Docker completely wrong and it's not suitable for this sort of thing. I thought that you could just copy an image load it and expect it to work, but it seems to need the exact directory structure that the image was built from, which means scp-ing the entire directory structure, which defeats the purpose of saving an image. I'm mystified.

I'm at the point where it looks like just creating a stack of ordinary VMs might be a better way to go. But I want to give Docker a proper go before giving up.

How can I copy an image from a local drive into a docker-machine and get it to work?

Comment: Did you try this: [How to copy docker images from one host to another without via repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository)?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you are using Windows  - are you running Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox?

Comment: MacOS with docker-machine installed, and virtual-box

Comment: @tgogos. I can copy the images without a problem, I can load the images I've copied without a problem. But I can't get them to run.