# How to deploy run docker image on server

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have created a website with multiple containers services via docker-compose and is running fine on my local machine. I have saved all images from local and loaded them in my server as describer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-via-repository) . Now I have a docker-compose.yaml file in local with all the configuration like ports, links specified in it. How do I run the same configuration on my server?

My configuration file is

```
version: '2'

volumes:
 dbdata:
  driver: local

services:
  webserver:
   container_name: "webserver"
   image: "sb/webserver:prod"
   restart: always
   ports:
    - 80:80
   build:
    context: ./sb-web
    dockerfile: Dockerfile

  app:
   container_name: "app"
   image: "sb/app:prod"
   restart: always
   build:
    context: ./sb-app
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
   working_dir: /usr/src/app
   depends_on:
    - webserver

  api:
   container_name: "api"
   image: "sb/api:prod"
   build:
   context: ./sb-api
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
   restart: always
   links:
    - database
   working_dir: /var/www/html
   depends_on:
    - webserver

  database:
   container_name: "database"
   image: "sb/database:prod"
   build:
    context: ./sb-db
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
     - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I didn't see a problem :) - maybe just copy the `docker-compose.yaml` to the server too and just start the containers?

Comment: removed build from yaml and called docker-compose up from server and is running now :) thanks