# Dockerizing ELK Stack for OpenShift (corporate)

Tags: docker, openshift, devops, elastic-stack

I'm new to docker and am currently working on dockerizing a simple ELK Stack application at work. I've seen several tutorials on how to do this, however my biggest issue is that I can't use *just any* existing docker image, as this is corporate code. So, from my understanding, I'll need dockerize/create 3 separate images of ELK from artifacts that we have currently available internally.  My current approach so far has been to get the rpms (using RHEL7), create a dockerfile to install/expose them ect.

Reason for my approach: I am working behind a corporate firewall and proxy and don't know if downloading an official docker image is possible nor if it is compliant

So far unsuccessful, but does anyone have experience doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `env` can not access through `internet` to `docker registry`  to download `docker images` right ? So you just want to get the docker image related with `EFK`, refer [How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository) for copy the images to your env.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My next question then would be figuring out whether or not this is compliant at my company.  Any thoughts on the general practice? Namely being do people typically do this in industry?

Comment: @user9058928, AFAIK yes, it usually does. Refer [Exporting images](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/disconnected_install.html#disconnected-preparing-images-for-export) for steps of disconnected installation on OpenShift(it's enterprise kubernetes).