# What is the purpose of pushing an image in a CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Context: Reading through [this](https://circleci.com/blog/build-cicd-piplines-using-docker/) blog post.

Pushing images to a registry seems to be the "right thing to do" ... but I don't understand why.

What purpose does this serve? Is it because the server I ssh into needs to have a local copy of the image? And to do that, one approach is to pull an image from a registry?

Comment: The home page for Docker Hub says "Build and Ship any Application Anywhere."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Couldn't I just upload an image from one machine (say a CI/CD server) via ssh? using dockerhub seems needlessly ceremonious to me. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226261/4259341) example (I know this api is deprecated but it illustrates my point).

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.  But there are reasons why people might not want to bother standing up their own machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you use a CI, CD pipeline when you want to streamline your build / test/ deploy process, and usually this happens if you have a production infrastructure to maintain that is actually critical to your business.

There is no need for a CI/CD pipeline if you're just playing around / prototyping IMO, in which case you can build you docker images on the machine directly, or ssh an image over. That's perfectly reasonable.

Look at the 'registry' as a repository of your binary image (i.e. a fixed version of your code that ideally is versioned and you know works)

Then deploying is as simple as telling your servers to pull the image and run it, from anywhere.

On a flexible architecture, you might have nodes coming up or going down at any time, and they need to be able to pull the latest code from somewhere to get back up and running automatically, at any time, without intervention.

Answer (score 2):

> What purpose does this serve? Is it because the server I ssh into needs to have a local copy of the image? And to do that, one approach is to pull an image from a registry?

From the CI/CD perspective, a docker registry is the equivalent of an artifact repository for images. You want a central source of these images to download from as you go from one docker host to another since your build server is most likely different than your dev and prod servers.

> Couldn't I just upload an image from one machine (say a CI/CD server) via ssh? using dockerhub seems needlessly ceremonious to me. Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226261/4259341) example (I know this api is deprecated but it illustrates my point).

It is possible to save/load images directly to a docker host, but there a few major downsides. First, you lose any benefit from docker's layered filesystem. When building an app in CI/CD, most of the time only the last few layers should need to be rebuilt with your application changes. There should be the same previous base image and various common layers to build your app that remain identical. With a registry, these common layers are seen, only the difference is pushed and pulled, making your deploys faster and saving you disk space. With a save/load command, all layers are sent every time since you do not know the state of the remote server when you run the save.

Second, this doesn't scale as you add hosts to run images. Every host would need the image copied on the chance you want to run it on that host, e.g. to handle failover or load balancing. It also won't work if you move to swarm mode or kubernetes since you could easily add new nodes to the cluster that won't have your image. Swarm mode defaults to looking up the sha256 of the image on the registry to guarantee the same image is always used even if the tag is modified on the registry after the initial deploy.

Keep in mind you can run your own registry server (there's a docker image and the api is open). Many artifact repositories (e.g. artifactory and nexus) include support for a docker registry. And many cloud providers include a registry with their container offerings. So you do not need to push to a remote docker hub to deploy locally.

One last point is that a registry server is useful to developers who can now pull the same image used in dev and prod to test against other microservices they are writing locally without the need to build everything locally or ssh to a CI/CD server or even prod to save and scp images back to their laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Registry is single source of truth in this case. It means, that you can have multiple nodes (servers), cluster(s) and have the single place from where you can get your images. Also if of your nodes drop-down - you can fast start your image in the new one. Also you can automate your image's updating using registry's webhook, for example when you add new version of image registry gonna send webhook to any service that can upgrade your containers to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Consider docker image as a new way of distribution of your software to your servers and docker-registry as a centralized storage of shared images(the like npm.org for js, maven.org for java).

**For example,**
if you develop *java application*, years before docker you may use `.jar` files to do it. The way docker image is better is that also include all OS level dependencies like `JDK`/`JRE` and system configurations. So this helps you to avoid "it works on my machine" effect.

To distribute `docker image` you can also use just docker file and build it all the time on every machine. `Docker-Repository` allows you to have centralized storage of pre-build images.

Pushing to docker-repository in your CI/CD allows to build your distributive once and further work with the same distributive both on integration and prod environments.

**Using just `Dockerfile` will not guarantee you the same state on every build in every moment of time because you may install external dependencies in your `Dockerfile` script which may be updated or even removed between two sequential builds.**