# Running local container when connected to remote docker machine?

Tags: docker

I'd like to deploy a container that I've built locally on a DigitalOcean droplet. I've been following [these](https://blog.machinebox.io/deploy-machine-box-in-digital-ocean-385265fbeafd) instructions. The problem is that by running:

```
eval $(docker-machine env DROPLET_NAME)
```

Docker sets the environment variables to be the remote machine, effectively changing the environment to running Docker on the remote machine. This is expected. However, say I have a local image I've built named `rb612/docker-img:latest` that I haven't pushed up to a remote. I want to run this in the remote machine context.

If I run:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8000 rb612/docker-img:latest
```

Then I get `Unable to find image 'rb612/docker-img:latest' locally`. If my understand is correct, this is because it's no longer running in the context of my machine. Opening a new shell and running the same command works fine without the remote environment variables set.

So I'm wondering if there's a way I can run this local image on my remote machine. I tried using the `-w` flag to pass in the local path but I got the same error. Deploying instead with a remote docker image works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'm wondering if there's a way I can run this local image on my remote machine.

Sure.

You have a couple of options.

### Using docker image save/load

1. You can use `docker image save` to save the image to a file.  Do this either before you run your `eval` statement, or do it in a different terminal window that doesn't have the remote Docker environment configured:

   ```
   docker image save rb612/docker-img:latest > docker-img.tar
   ```
2. After running your `eval $(...)` command, use `docker image load` to send the image to your remote Docker:

   ```
   docker image load < docker-img.tar
   ```

Now the image is available on your remote Docker host and you can `docker run` it normally.

### Set up a remote registry

You can set up your own remote registry, in which case you can simply `docker push` to that registry from your local machine and `docker pull` from the remote machine.  This is generally the best long-term solution, but the initial set up (especially securing things properly with SSL) is a little bit more involved.  Details are in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/).

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much. Works like a charm. Just out of curiosity, I was also attempting to do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/3813411 by copying the `.tar` image to the remote at path `/home/test.tar` using `docker-machine scp` but I wasn't able to load by doing `docker load -i my_machine_name:/home/test.tar`. It also couldn't find it by doing `docker load -i /home/test.tar` either. Was I doing something wrong? It didn't seem like I could specify a path in the remote machine.