# Azure Release Pipeline for Docker Image after Build Pipeline is Successful

Tags: azure, docker, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to build a docker image in a Build Pipeline and Pushing to ACR (Azure Container Registry) in a Release Pipeline. To me it makes the most sense to have those responsibilities distributed.

I have a Docker image building in a build pipeline and pushing it in the next task of that pipeline to the container registry - and trying to make an Artifact of just the image so I can use in a release pipeline instead of pushing in the build pipeline - but the artifact I get is all the source code from src directory - I have tried all the defaults- artifact directory etc

1. Where is the image saved when task is build docker image?
2. Can I make that my artifact to use in Release Pipeline?
3. I want an version number now using :latest only thing that works
4. Should I just make several builds like the one that is pushing successfully
   to push to staging and UAT?
5. Any other suggested workflow for Azure Devops Docker Build and Publish?

Comment: you aware you have 5* questions in one "question?

Comment: Hope this helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository