# Store local docker images in the cloud

Tags: macos, docker

Is it possible instead of storing docker containers/images locally on my MacBook Pro *(from docker build, or dockerfiles)*, to store them on a cloud storage provider like AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage? My MacBook Pro only has 256GB of disk, and I am constantly running out of disk space and I have to run `docker image prune -a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository)

Comment: External drives may be part of the solution here. Even a USB stick can help out and a 256GB USB 3.0 drive isn't that expensive. If you're really strapped for space you can also build your images on a cloud VM.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of services outthere were you can store your images, those are called docker registry hubs. Some of them are [Dockerhub](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html), [Azure AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/), AWS [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/), Google also has its [own](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/). 
You can also create your own with docker registry as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your images in repos on Docker Hub. They have a guide on how to do it, and you can also use this guide: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html

Comment: When I run `docker build` it still does the build locally though. Docker push just pushes the finished container up to hub.

Comment: Do you want to build and store on the cloud? Or just store?

Comment: Just store. For example when I run `docker images` it shows about 30GB of images locally.

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to upload the built container to something like google drive, but if you want to have them running in the cloud, you will probably end up paying for something like an AWS EC2 instance.