# Docker Image size discrepency between local and remote

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have an image hosted in my private repos. I noticed that the same image in the remote repos has 50% smaller in size than the copy I have on my local machine after pulling (7GB vs 15GB). This image is built on IIS image. My question is does docker hub compressed image?

Comment: Which image are you refering to?

Comment: @PierreB.I updated my orginial post for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old topic. You can check some discussions regarding this subject:

- [Issue #331 from hub-feedback](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/331)
- [Issue #242 from hub-feedback](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/242)

It seems like during `docker push` the image is compressed. While the hub shows the compressed size (although not much clear about it) representing what will be over the network, `docker-images` shows the uncompressed size.

Answer (score 5):

You can compress your image using `docker save` command.

```
docker save your_image | gzip > your_image.tar.gz
```

Now run `ls -hl` you will see the image is compressed and it size approximate decrease to its half or depend upon layer.

Save an image to a tar.gz file using gzip:

> You can use gzip to save the image file and make the backup smaller.
>
> `docker save myimage:latest | gzip > myimage_latest.tar.gz`

[save docker image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

You can load the image or share the file with other so all the need to load it back as a docker image.

```
docker load < your_image.tar.gz
```

> Load an image or repository from a tar archive (even if compressed
>   with gzip, bzip2, or xz) from a file or STDIN. It restores both images
>   and tags.

An example of centos which is around 200MB and the gzip file is just 70MB

[image]

So you can compress your local image the same and you can expect upto 7GB gzip file.