# How to compress the latest docker image?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I want to compress (and later send with rsync to other server) my last backup Docker images for automated.
I try this:

```
sudo docker save -o dockdebian.tar.gz | sudo docker images | awk 'NR==2{ print $3 }'
```

Select the the first ID of the image list. 
But gave me this error:

> "docker save" requires at least 1 argument.
>
> See 'docker save --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
>
> Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
>
> xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. You need to tell `docker save` what image you want to save!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use command substitution in shell. More info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

```
docker save -o dockdebian.tar $(sudo docker images | awk 'NR==2{ print $3 }')
```

or

```
docker save -o dockdebian.tar `sudo docker images | awk 'NR==2{ print $3 }'`
```

Comment: Using `.gz` extension is misleading. `docker save` creates a usual tar archive, it is not compressed in any way. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#extended-description.

Comment: you are right. I edited my post.

Comment: Also: To get the first Image-ID `docker images --format "{{.ID}}"|head -1`

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the compression part, you can omit the `-o` so `docker save` writes to stdout then pipe that into the compressor of your choice. Eg:

```
docker save my-image:latest | xz > my-image.tar.xz
```

I'm not sure the intent with your `sudo docker images | awk 'NR==2{ print $3 }'` bit, for me (as an SRE) that ID could be any number of images as I'm constantly shuffling between projects. Even if you only ever build one image you should probably specify the image tag intentionally to prevent issues down the line. Also, if you're finding you need sudo with docker, you may want to peruse this page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user