# Error response from daemon: the daemon on this operating system does not support exporting Windows containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-container, docker-command

Is there another way to transport a container image between 2 private hosts, without using docker hub?

I am running docker Desktop 2.1 on windows 10 (latest version).

**Update**

Note: I look for a solution for windows containers, running on windows 10 and windows server. Also, i don't intent to use a docker hub for this purpose. So, solutions must not use linux available functions or hubs.

Comment: The question says explicit windows containers, that are a subset of docker containers. Also, the question discards solution involving a docker hub. So the question is well formed but the potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository does not apply

Comment: I would expect `docker save` and `docker load` to still work on Windows images.

Comment: Yes, it works. From documentation is almost the same as export and import.