# How to set minikube proxy when the driver is hyperkit or virtualbox?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, minikube, nginx-ingress

I am trying to use Ingress in minikube by `minikube addons enable ingress`. However, currently Ingress cannot be used with minikube when the driver is `docker` on macOS based on this [issue ticket](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332).

So I turn to use `hyperkit` or `virtualbox` as driver. One image that need to be pulled when enabling Ingress is `k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0`. However, k8s.gcr.io is blocked in my current location.

So I try to use a VPN in global mode for my computer. However, I met [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6296) that hyperkit is unable to access k8s.gcr.io when the VPN is in use.

Then I found this document
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/

My VPN is listening at 127.0.0.1:1087, I set

```sh
export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1087
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:1087
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.99.0/24,192.168.39.0/24
```

Then I tried all these methods to start minikube:

```sh
minikube start --driver=hyperkit
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
minikube start --driver=hyperkit --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1087 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:1087 --docker-env NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.99.0/24,192.168.39.0/24
```

But I saw these messages:

```sh
  minikube v1.21.0 on Darwin 11.2.3
✨  Using the hyperkit driver based on user configuration
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating hyperkit VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
```

and

```sh
  minikube v1.21.0 on Darwin 11.2.3
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
❗  Local proxy ignored: not passing HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:1087 to docker env.
```

Seems this "user configuration" overwrite my proxy config. But where is this "user configuration"?

What is the correct way to set proxy for minikube when the drive `hyperkit` or `virtualbox`? Thanks!

Comment: How about downloading this image using docker, exporting it to file, transfering it to minikube VM and importing it to local docker registry, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/15537201?

Comment: Also, from https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6296#issuecomment-579921953 it looks like only hyperkit is problematic, have you tried global VPN on virtualbox without any settings related to VPN on minikube?

Comment: Thanks @JakubSiemaszko ! Transferring it to minikube VM sounds a good way! I did try minikube with virtualbox but got same issue. Feel free to post as an answer as it does help.

Comment: Done, feel free to accept and upvote this answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 127.0.0.1 conflicts with the VM's internal 127.0.0.1 address, and that's why it's ignored. You might need to configure your proxy to be your host's network IP instead of 127.0.0.1? You might not even need to configure a proxy? Also, the Virtualbox driver gives me problems with VPN. I have the best luck with the VMware driver, and can also get the HyperKit driver to work if I update the VM's DNS to my host's DNS.

```
minikube start --driver hyperkit
minikube ssh sudo resolvectl dns eth0 192.168.0.53
minikube ssh sudo resolvectl domain eth0 example.com
```

I also get the `unable to access k8s.gcr.io` error when creating the VM, but it doesn't seem to affect things.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading this image using docker, exporting it to file, transfering it to minikube VM and importing it to local docker registry, like [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/15537201) has solved the problem.

Comment: how to transfer a local docker image into minikube?

Comment: try this 'minikube image load <image>'

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy is for circumventing the China Greate Firewall correct? Then I know why it is not working. It is not releated to hyperkit or virutalbox at all.

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/f567893cdbb8e98a0348c1d93455af71cf6ce12c/pkg/minikube/proxy/proxy.go) of minikube. "Local proxy ignored" actually means that your proxy url is set to localhost (127.0.*) and minikube thinks you set the proxy incorrectly so it will just ignore this setting.

The resolution is just to edit your host file (for Windows it is in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), to give 127.0.0.1 a hostname. You can add the following line into the end of the host file.

`127.0.0.1 localproxy`

Then change environment variable `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to `http://localproxy:1235`.

Reopen the CMD window to get the updated environment variable and restart the minikue. You should be able to find that the "Local proxy ignored" message is gone and finally you can download the image from gcr.io.