# How can I access wsl2 which is used by Docker desktop?

Tags: docker, windows-10, wsl-2

I want to transfer a Docker image from my Windows10 PC to another one, Fedora, using rsync. I can't use WSL, I need WSL2 as the compiler says:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ docker images                                                                                                                                                                                      
The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.                                                           
We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate                                                               
the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit:                                                                                                                                                                                       
https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/
```

But I think that as I have Docker desktop it is using WSL2:

[image]

But I don't know how to run the wsl2 Docker is using for my own.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         1
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

Comment: Please specify what sort of "access" you mean.

Comment: on your config page of Docker Desktop there is an option to use WSL2 based engine, check it and it should work on top of WSL2

Comment: Sure @MathiasNikkel where is the config page on Docker Desktop?

Comment: On your screen, there is an Settings option on the header, there it has an General tab, where this config lives
like so: [link]https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/784092634532675626/923579082837471262/unknown.png

Comment: This question seems necessary, because now that Docker Desktop uses WSL2, the only config options they (or anyone) describe use .wslconfig. But, if I understand correctly, that configures WSL2 for *everything*. I don't want to configure every single WSL2 instance just to constrain (or expand) Docker. Docker isn't the center of my world. I want to only constrain all Docker WSL2 instances. Is this not applicable somehow? Is my presumption of WSL2 configuration and Docker's relationship to it bad? If so, such things could be made a lot clearer by people.

Answer (score 4):

You can access docker desktop WSL using the following command

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker Desktop images, containers, and volumes are stored in the special `docker-desktop-data`.  As noted in [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1613589/1210833) and my answer there, `docker-desktop-data` is not bootable (by design).

If you *really* had to get to the filesystem, I've documented a way to do so there.  But in general, you should *not* need to do this.

Instead, use the normal `docker` commands (from WSL2, PowerShell, or CMD) to save the image to a `tar` file as documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23938978/11810933):

```
docker save -o <image.tar> <image_name>
```

Then transfer the file using `rsync` or other means, and on the destination machine, import it via:

```
docker load -i <image.tar>
```

---

Again, that's from WSL2, PowerShell, or CMD.  But in your case, the Ubuntu instance is WSL1.  That won't work for Docker.  You'll need to convert it to WSL2.

Just in case, I always recommend backing up your instance before converting it.  From PowerShell:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu_backup.tar
```

Then, once you have the backup:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
wsl --set-default-version 2 # if desired
```

After conversion, you shouldn't see that error when running `docker` in Ubuntu.

---

Side note -- Docker Desktop "injects" the `docker` command into any WSL2 instance that you set in the "WSL Integration" tab in Settings.  This should default to your "default" WSL2 instance, which (from your screenshot) is Ubuntu.  The "real" `docker` command is inside `docker-desktop`, but it's linked into Ubuntu for you.

So by default, you should have all `docker` functionality directly in your `Ubuntu` instance.  Neither `docker-desktop` nor `docker-desktop-data` are designed to be used directly by the end-user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer NotTheDr01ds. So I should upgrade my wsl?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I didn't notice the Ubuntu instance was set to version 1.  I'll update my answer, but yes.  Wait for the edited directions first, just to be sure.

Comment: You should also be able to use it from PowerShell (or CMD), though, if you want to try that.  Shouldn't need anything extra for that to work.