# Run docker image on separate machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a network server let's say IP: 192.168.0.1 where I have docker running and my development machine a laptop with IP 192.168.0.2.

After I build the image locally on my laptop, how I can run it on the main server on port 80 or 443?

Comment: What command are you using to run the build? The port in which your service will run depends on what port mapping you assign to it https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository)

Comment: I need to run this from my laptop, that means I cannot copy it to the server and then do docker run on the server.... can it all be done/triggered from my laptop?