# Moving local docker images to minikube (image persistency)

Tags: docker, minikube

Hey guys this is a quick question to see if it's possible to move the images stored on your local PC into minikube, without having to keep building them within minikube.

##### My Problem:

My problem is that everytime I restart my computer I would have to rebuild the images by using the `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command to connect my shell session to the minikube docker daemon. However, the images that you build on using your local daemon are persistent upon restart or shutdown. Is there a way to move these images into minikube so that the minikube docker daemon can pick them up, or else a way to pull those images straight from my local PC?

Comment: this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. That is what I was looking for. The link you sent also has a "does this answer your question" link which suits my needs perfectly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository)

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to save your existing container back to an image (recommend using a new image name), run:

  *docker commit -p CONTAINER_ID NEW_IMAGE_NAME*
- You can then export the image into a tarball via:

  *docker save -o savedIMG.tar  NEW_IMAGE_NAME*
- Determine the IP address of the Minikube container via: "*minikube ip*".  It will likely be 192.168.49.2.  Your host machine will be 192.168.49.1.
- You then connect to the Minikube container via "*minikube ssh*" and scp the tarball from your host server.  Example:

  *scp bob@192.168.49.1:/home/bob/savedIMG.tar .*

(Note the space+period at the end)

- You then import the image from the tarball via:

  *docker load --input savedIMG.tar*

Comment: All that said, it may be easier to stand up a registry on the host machine.